# find an angle in $\mathbb{R^3}$ between vectors defined by dot and cross products

Tags: vectors

First all, Merry Christmas to everyone!

I am stuck and need help!

Three vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, $\vec a$, $\vec b $  and $\vec c$, where $\vec b$ is a unit vector, and $\vec c$ is defined as

$\vec c$ = ($\vec a$ . $\vec b$) $\vec b$ + [$\vec a$ - ($\vec a$ . $\vec b$)$ \vec b$] $cos(\alpha)$ + [$\vec a$ $\times$ $\vec b$] $sin(\alpha)$

What do the square brackets mean? how can the sum of a dot product and a cross product be a vector?

I want to find out an angle between $\vec c$ and $\vec b$.  But I do not understand the equation of $\vec b$ and can't work out $\vec b$.

Please help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: `how can the sum of a dot product and a cross product` You are misreading the expression. All those are vectors on the RHS: $\vec c$ = ($\vec a$ . $\vec b$) $\color{red}{\vec b}$ + [$\color{red}{\vec a}$ - ($\vec a$ . $\vec b$)$ \color{red}{\vec b}$] $cos(\alpha)$ + [$\color{red}{\vec a \times \vec b}$] $sin(\alpha)$.

Comment: You made me think the question had something to do with Christmas.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, dxiv.  Can you help me understand this question?

Comment: Merry Christmas yanko

Comment: $$b\cdot c=(a\cdot b)(b\cdot b)+(a\cdot b)(1-b\cdot b)\cos\alpha$$
$$=a\cdot b$$

Comment: I think [$\vec a$ - ($\vec a$ . $\vec b$)$ \vec b$] $cos(\alpha)$  is a dot product and  [$\vec a$ $\times$ $\vec b$] $sin(\alpha)$ is a cross product. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Newbee $\cos (\alpha)$ is a scalar that multiplies the vector $\vec a - (\vec a \cdot \vec b) \vec b\,$.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, velut luna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: using that $\vec b \cdot \vec b = |\vec b|^2=1$ and $(\vec a \times \vec b) \cdot \vec b = 0\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\vec c \cdot \vec b = (\vec a \cdot \vec b) \,\vec b \cdot \vec b + (\cancel{\vec a \cdot \vec b} - \cancel{(\vec a \cdot \vec b) \,\vec b \cdot \vec b}) \cos(\alpha) + \xcancel{(\vec a \times \vec b) \cdot \vec b \sin(\alpha)} = \vec a \cdot \vec b
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, dxiv. I think I need to spend some time on the revision of vector.